# What's the custom css to change the colour of a font awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

Appreciate your answers to a debut question on Stack Overflow from a code newbie.

I want to change the colour of my font awesome icons on the homepage of my wordpress theme (arcade pro) using the custom css editor - can you suggest the css to try?

*Each icon (like the fa-trophy in example below) is within a custom text widget created by the theme developer. He has set up pre-set colours, I'd just like to use my own hex code. Thanks.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="http://webaddress.com/?s=yorkshire+county+cricket+club">
  <i class="info fa fa-trophy"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `color` property.

```css
a .fa-trophy {  /* Use '.fa' if you want to select all icons at once*/
  color: #deb887
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="http://webaddress.com/?s=yorkshire+county+cricket+club">
  <i class="info fa fa-trophy fa-5x"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, it now opens up a world of possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just change the text with *color: #AA0000*. To select all icons of font-awesome, use this (assuming the icon is in a *i* tag

```
i[class*="fa-"] {
    color: #AA0000;
}
```

The above selector selects all instances of the  tag with classes that start with *fa-* allowing you to select all font-awesome icons at once.

If your icon is not within an *i* tag, just find the matching tag and replace the selector.

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Thanks for the introduction to JSfiddle, helpful in deconstructing and ultimately finding the answer.

Comment: @ThomasBormans This worked in the sense that I noticed it did change an icon to the new colour within the website but not in the widget area where the icon was. Still useful for future endeavours so thanks.

Comment: @John_F That is possible. Probably because the css of the widget gets loaded after your css or because the css selector of the widget is more precise. Let me know if you have any problems setting the color and I will gladly take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

To change all icons to one color, you can do:

```
i.fa {
    color:#cccccc;
}
```

However, your question seems to ask about changing them **only on your homepage**.  Most Wordpress themes will tack on an additional unique class to the  element or one of the wrapping s.  If you want to explicitly target your homepage, search for that class and prepend it to the css from above, like so:

```
.your-homepage-class i.fa {
    color:#cccccc
}
```

If you post a link to your site I can give you a 100% complete answer.

**Edit -- just noticed that it's your debut question -- this is my 2nd answer ever :P.**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. A simple enough amend seemingly but has been anything but. What actually happened is that several suggestions here partially worked (in the sense that you flagged up using the color property and I saw they did change icons elsewhere.

Then that eureka moment. The homepage widget area (where the icons I wanted to change were encased) felt like the problem so this worked perfectly across all icons as I wanted:

.bavotasan_custom_text_widget i.info {
    color: #bed730;
    border-color: #bed730

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Font Awesome CSS](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

CSS:

```
 .fa-fish {
      color: salmon;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="fas fa-fish"></i>
```